# having buffers list as quickfix window in vim editor?

Tags: vim, editor, buffer, vi, vim-plugin

Using vim editor, a common task is to browse buffers.
I now use standard commands like `:ls` or a `:cnext`

I would like to browse buffers as list in quickfix window,
in the simple (=excellent) way MRU plugin (https://github.com/yegappan/mru) implement.

There is a plugin simple as MRU files but acting on buffers ?

OK, a possible solution could be to use `:CtrlpBuffers` command, part of Ctrlp plugin (https://github.com/kien/ctrlp.vim) but I'm not a big fan of Ctrlp, that have sometime beahviours I do not fully understand (the fuzzy choices...); so I'm look for something really simple as MRU plugin.

BTW, I joked with `:cexpr {expr}` command, trying populate the quickfix windows with content of `:buffers` list, without success (maybe because my ignorance programming vimscripts)

Any suggestion ?

thanks
giorgio

Comment: Questions about `vim` should be better ask at http://vi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: related: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2121/how-do-i-have-buffers-listed-in-a-quickfix-window-in-vim

Answer (score 5):

Have a look at the [bufexplorer plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=42). It opens a browsable list of all buffers in a sidebar, similar to the mentioned MRU plugin. Also, there are several more such plugins on [vim.org](http://www.vim.org/).